# Why is the JSON.stringify() replacer function not working?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8tAyu/7/

```
var foo = {
    "foundation": "Mozilla",
    "model": "box",
    "week": 45,
    "transport": {
        "week": 3
    },
    "month": 7
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, 
                           function(k, v) { 
                               if (k === "week") 
                                   return v;
                               else 
                                   return undefined;
                           }));
```

so supposedly, I thought at least the "week" that isn't nested should come back, and I will see how to make the nested one come back too.  But no matter how I change it, the `console.log` prints out `undefined`, unless if I change the function simply to `return v` always, then I get back the whole object.  Why is that?

Comment: Because the first call to the replacer sends in `""` (an empty string), and you return `undefined`, effectively halting the conversion process.

Comment: MDN docs: [The replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter)

Comment: I kind of wonder why the initial pass is for... it seems we need to "specially handle it"... if that first pass with the empty key and value as the object is not done, we can always do some special processing if we need that first pass... and actually, I don't see a reason of needing that first pass

Answer (score 5):

Stringify seems to be called, first, with an empty 'k' for the root of the object. We return undefined for that, and all processing stops.

If we change it to:

```
if (!k || (k == "week") )
```

then the result is:

```
{"week":45}
```

You won't get the nested one, since we return `undefined` for "transport" and ignore all its contents.

Comment: but what if the object `foo` has a property with the name of empty string, such as in http://jsfiddle.net/8tAyu/16/ then it will include it too

Comment: @動靜能量: You should also do `v && typeof v === "object"`. And then if you want the nested week, get rid of the `!k` part.

Comment: @squint can you give the full code... or else do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/8tAyu/27/ and it won't work...

Comment: @動靜能量: What result do you want? Do you also want the nested `week` to be included?

Comment: I want... how about: `{"week":45, "week":3}` but the second property will replace the first one... but what if I want `week` and `year` and the `year` is nested?